# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'

Tags: solidity, hardhat

*Many thanks in advance for your time and help*

**I want to run flashloan between uniswap and sushiswap.** But, I get this error and it persists, despite trying several potential solutions mentioned by answers to similar problem.
**I wrote it with hardhat via vscode.**

**here is the error:**
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'

**Here is the solidity code:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

// Uniswap interface and library imports
import "./libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol";
import "./libraries/SafeERC20.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";

contract FlashloanSwap {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    // Define the factory and router addresses of the DEXs
    address private constant UNISWAP_FACTORY =
        0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f;
    address private constant UNISWAP_ROUTER =
        0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address private constant SUSHISWAP_FACTORY =
        0xC0AEe478e3658e2610c5F7A4A2E1777cE9e4f2Ac;
    address private constant SUSHISWAP_ROUTER =
        0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F;

// Trade variables
uint256 private deadline = block.timestamp + 1 days;

// Get the contract balance of token
function getBalanceOfToken(address _address) public view returns (uint256) {
    return IERC20(_address).balanceOf(address(this));
}


function checkProfitability(uint256 _input, uint256 _outPut)
    private
    pure
    returns (bool)
{
    return _outPut > _input;
}

// There must be a function to receive ETH
receive() external payable {}
fallback() external payable {}

// Eth balance needs to be checked sometimes
function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
}

// Define a function to trade a given token in exchange for another token on a given DEX
function executeTrade(
    address _fromToken,
    address _toToken,
    uint256 _amountIn,
    address factory,
    address router
) private returns (uint256) {
    address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(_fromToken, _toToken);
    require(pair != address(0), "Pool does not exist");

    // Calculate amount out
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = _fromToken;
    path[1] = _toToken;

    uint256 amountRequired = IUniswapV2Router01(router).getAmountsOut(
        _amountIn,
        path
    )[1];

    console.log("Amount Required: ", amountRequired);

    // Perform arbitrage - Swap for another token
    IUniswapV2Router02(router)
        .swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            _amountIn,
            amountRequired,
            path,
            address(this),
            deadline
        );

    uint256 balanceA = getBalanceOfToken(_fromToken);
    uint256 balanceB = getBalanceOfToken(_toToken);

    uint256 amountReceived = balanceA == 0 ? balanceB : balanceA;

    console.log("amountReceived: ", amountReceived);

    require(amountReceived > 0, "Aborted Transaction");
    return amountReceived;
}

/* 
I) It will be run whenever an arbitrage opportunity is detected 
*/
function runTheArbitrage(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint256 amountA,
    uint256 amountB
) external {
    // Get the pair address on uniswap
    address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(UNISWAP_FACTORY).getPair(
        tokenA,
        tokenB
    );

    
    // Check whether the pair exists
    require(
        pairAddress != address(0),
        "The pair does not exist on uniswap"
    );

           
    // Save the borrowed token's specifications in _data to be passed to uniswapV2Call
    address borrowedTokenAddress = amountA == 0 ? tokenB : tokenA;
    uint256 borrowedTokenAmount = amountA == 0 ? amountB : amountA;
    bytes memory data = abi.encode(
        borrowedTokenAddress,
        borrowedTokenAmount
    );

    // Create the flashloan with the swap function
    IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap(amountA, amountB, address(this), data);

}

/* 
II) With executing the previous function, uniswap will call this function in order to complete the flashloan cycle
*/
function uniswapV2Call(
    address _sender,
    uint256 _amountA,
    uint256 _amountB,
    bytes calldata _data
) external {
    
    // get the specifications of the borrowed token
    address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token0();
    address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();
    (address borrowedTokenAddress, uint256 borrowedTokenAmount) = abi
        .decode(_data, (address, uint256));
    token0 = token0 == borrowedTokenAddress ? token0 : token1;
    token1 = token0 == borrowedTokenAddress ? token1 : token0;


    // Check whether this function is called only by the pair contracts of uniswap
    require(
        msg.sender ==
            UniswapV2Library.pairFor(UNISWAP_FACTORY, token0, token1),
        "Only requests from uniswap pair contracts are accepted"
    );


    // Check whether this contract is the sender
    require(_sender == address(this), "Sender should match this contract");

    // Check one of the amounts to be zero
    require(
        _amountA == 0 || _amountB == 0,
        "One of the amounts must be zero"
    );


    // Execute the first swap on source DEX
    IERC20(token0).safeIncreaseAllowance(
        UNISWAP_ROUTER,
        borrowedTokenAmount
    );
    uint256 firstAmountOut = executeTrade(
        token0,
        token1,
        borrowedTokenAmount,
        UNISWAP_FACTORY,
        UNISWAP_ROUTER
    );

    // Aprove the second DEX to spend the swapped token, then execute the trade on it
    IERC20(token1).safeIncreaseAllowance(SUSHISWAP_ROUTER, firstAmountOut);
    uint256 secondAmountOut = executeTrade(
        token1,
        token0,
        firstAmountOut,
        SUSHISWAP_FACTORY,
        SUSHISWAP_ROUTER
    );


    uint256 fee = ((borrowedTokenAmount * 3) / 997) + 1;
    uint256 amountToBePaidBack = borrowedTokenAmount + fee;

    
    // Check profitability
    bool profCheck = checkProfitability(
        amountToBePaidBack,
        secondAmountOut
    );
    require(profCheck, "Arbitrage not profitable");

    
    // Pay back the loan
    bool success1 = IERC20(token0).transfer(msg.sender, amountToBePaidBack);


    // Send the profit to the initiator of the transaction
    bool success2 = IERC20(token0).transfer(
        tx.origin,
        secondAmountOut - amountToBePaidBack
    );

    console.log(secondAmountOut - amountToBePaidBack, success2);
}
}
```

**Also here is the hardhat.config.js file for the hardhat test**

```
const { version } = require("chai");

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require('dotenv').config();



module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {version: '0.5.5'}, 
      {version: '0.6.6'}, 
      {version: '0.8.8'},
    ],
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: process.env.alchemy_mainnet_key,
      },
    },
    testnet: {
      url: process.env.alchemy_renkiby_api,
      chainId: 97,
      accounts: [
        process.enc.test_private_key
      ],
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: process.env.alchemy_mainnet_key,
      chainId: 56,
      accounts: [
        process.env.private_key
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

**And finally, here is my test code**

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, waffle } = require("hardhat");
const { deployContract } = require("ethereum-waffle");
const provider = waffle.provider;
const { abi } = require('../artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol/IERC20.json');

describe("Checking the whole arbitrage process", function () {

  // Get the factory and router addresses
  const UNISWAP_FACTORY = "0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f";
  const UNISWAP_ROUTER = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";
  const SUSHI_FACTORY = "0xC0AEe478e3658e2610c5F7A4A2E1777cE9e4f2Ac";
  const SUSHI_ROUTER = "0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F";

  // Token addresses
  const tokenA = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
  const tokenB = "0x0F5D2fB29fb7d3CFeE444a200298f468908cC942";

  // Get the decimals
  const decimals = 18;

  beforeEach(async function () {

    // Get owner as signer
    [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    // Deploy smart contract
    const FlashloanSwap = await ethers.getContractFactory("FlashloanSwap");
    flashloanSwap = await FlashloanSwap.deploy();
    await flashloanSwap.deployed();

    console.log('\n', "Contract is deployed by: ", owner.address);
    console.log("contract is deployed to: ", flashloanSwap.address, '\n');

    const transactionHash = await owner.sendTransaction({
      to: flashloanSwap.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
    });
    console.log("transactionHash : ", transactionHash);

    balanceOfEth = await provider.getBalance(flashloanSwap.address)
    balanceOfEth = ethers.utils.formatUnits(balanceOfEth, 18);
    console.log('\n', "Balance of ETH before transaction : ", balanceOfEth.toString(), '\n');
  });

  
  it("Check Whether Swap Occurs or Not", async () => {
    await flashloanSwap.runTheArbitrage(tokenA, tokenB, 0, 100);
    
    balanceOfEth = await provider.getBalance(flashloanSwap.address)
    balanceOfEth = ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceOfEth, 18);
    
    console.log('\n', "Balance of ETH after transaction : ", balanceOfEth, '\n');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to pay back the loan + fees, you transfer the amount for each asset from your FlashloanSwap to Uniswap. Could the exception you're getting be thrown because you have to allow Uniswap to pull the loan + fees from your account, i.e. you call approve on uniswap and uniswap calls transferFrom on your account?

Try replacing:

```
IERC20(token0).transfer(msg.sender, amountToBePaidBack);`
```

with:

```
IERC20(token0).approve(msg.sender, amountToBePaidBack);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In fact, when you call a liquidity pool for flashloan on uniswap, it will call a function named uniswapV2Call on your smart contract which do all the arbitrage in just one block and in one transaction.
I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work and the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

100% sure that it's an allowance issue, you didn't approved the tokens like:

```
 IERC20(WETH).approve(routerA, amount);

        IUniswapV2Router02(routerA).swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amount, 
            0, 
            path2, 
            cttAddress, 
            block.timestamp + 1200
        );
```